# Why binding in template not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-compiler

I have a question regarding angular-tree-control usage, why {{node.label}} in below code is not binding successfully...
For example, i have a custom node template like below:

```
<ul {{options.ulClass}}>
     <li ng-repeat="node in node.{{options.nodeChildren}} | filter:filterExpression:filterComparator {{options.orderBy}}"
         ng-class="headClass(node)"
         {{options.liClass}}
         set-node-to-data>
          {{node.label}}
         <i class="tree-branch-head" ng-class="iBranchClass()" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i>
         <i class="tree-leaf-head {{options.iLeafClass}}"></i>
         <i>
             <b>
                 <div class="tree-label {{options.labelClass}}" ng-class="[selectedClass(), unselectableClass()]"
                      ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" tree-transclude></div>
             </b>
         </i>
         <treeitem ng-show="nodeExpanded()"></treeitem>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Here the {{node.label}} binding is not working, how can i make it binding.

I have created a simple plnkr to make it clear:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WdnJhmuZtibU0AyiDU3s?p=preview

**Question:**

In plnkr 'scripts.js' line 8, why {{node.label}} is not binding well.

I have used angular-tree-control a lot in our project, in some scenarios we want have some dynamic percentage value in front of the node icon. That's why i need the binding here.

Comment: 1.Using same node  object 
2.node in node.{{options.nodeChildren}}   ,  you are looping on $scope.node , is it have data ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple wrong expression have been used on HTML, that will not work

1. `{{options.ulClass}}` is seems to be wrong, angularjs doesn't add attribute using `{{}}`(interpolation). It should be `ng-class="options.ulClass"`
2. Also `ng-repeat` has wrong expression

   ```
   ng-repeat="node in node[options.nodeChildren] 
           | filter:filterExpression:filterComparator(options.orderBy)"
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Have you ever had a chance to look at the plnkr? Can you help to make it work, the 2 issues you mentioned seems not correct, this template is a String, and it will do interpolation and compilation in treeControl directive. Please help to see the plnkr for the whole code